# swift table section header duplicating on scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am admitting defeat with these custom headers in Swift.  I have tried for days to prevent the labels and images inside of the section headers from duplicating. Basically on scroll the labels/images inside the headers duplicate and lay on top of each other.

Would someone please for the love of god explain to me why this is happening and how to fix it.

The circular image keeps creating images and laying them on top of the previous, the same with the name and date labels!!

[image]

Here is my ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {

    @IBOutlet weak var navigationBar: UINavigationItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var list = []
    var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer!
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func getListBro() -> NSArray {
        return list
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        tableView.dataSource = self;
        tableView.delegate = self;
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension


        let streamURL = NSURL(string: "http://192.241.174.8:8000/beat-stream-all/")!

        let stuff = GetBeatStream(url:streamURL)
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50.0; //
        stuff.downloadJSONFromURL {
            (let jsonDictionary) in
                if let jsonList = jsonDictionary["results"] as? NSArray {
                    self.list = jsonList
                }


                let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
                    // do some task
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        // update some UI
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
        }
    }//end view did load



    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("streamCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! StreamTableViewCell

        cell.beatCover.image = UIImage(named: "imgres")

        if let id = list[indexPath.section] as? NSDictionary {
            if let beatID = id["id"] as? NSInteger {
                cell.setID(beatID)
            }
        }

        if let beat_cover = list[indexPath.section] as? NSDictionary {
            if let beat_cover_image = beat_cover["beat_cover"] as? String {
                cell.beatCover.downloadImageFrom(link: beat_cover_image, contentMode: UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill)  //set your image from link array.
            }
        }



        if let audio = list[indexPath.section] as? NSDictionary {
            if let audio_url = audio["audio"] as? String {
                    cell.url = audio_url
                    cell.buildPlayer()
            }
        }

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return list.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {


        let beatAuthorLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(55, 5, 200, 40))

        //USER PIC
        let profilePictureImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(5, 5, 40, 40));
        profilePictureImageView.layer.borderWidth = 0
        profilePictureImageView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        profilePictureImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        profilePictureImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profilePictureImageView.frame.height/2
        profilePictureImageView.clipsToBounds = true
        profilePictureImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true

        profilePictureImageView.image = UIImage(named: "imgres")  //set placeholder image first.

        if let userPicSection = list[section] as? NSDictionary {
            if let artist = userPicSection["artist"] as? NSDictionary {
                if let profilePic = artist["profile_pic"] as? String {
                    profilePictureImageView.downloadImageFrom(link: profilePic, contentMode: UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit) 
                }
            }
        }


        if let nameSection = list[section] as? NSDictionary {
            if let name = nameSection["artist"] as? NSDictionary {
                if let adminName = name["admin_name"] as? NSString {
                    print(adminName)
                    beatAuthorLabel.text = adminName as String
                    beatAuthorLabel.font = UIFont(name: beatAuthorLabel.font.fontName, size: 14)
                }
            }
        }






        var dateLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(225, 5, 200, 40))
        if let created = list[section] as? NSDictionary {
            if let date = created["created_at"] as? String {
                dateLabel.text = date as String
                dateLabel.font = UIFont(name: dateLabel.font.fontName, size: 8)
            }
        }

        let header: UITableViewHeaderFooterView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
        header.contentView.addSubview(beatAuthorLabel)
        header.contentView.addSubview(dateLabel)
        header.contentView.addSubview(dateLabel)
        header.contentView.addSubview(profilePictureImageView)
        header.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 179/255, green: 194/255, blue: 191/255, alpha:1)
        header.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        header.alpha = 1
    }



    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)! as! StreamTableViewCell
        currentCell.player.play()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let leavingCell = cell as! StreamTableViewCell
        leavingCell.player.pause()
    }
}
```

Comment: Header views get reused. But your code creates and adds new labels and image views over and over ever time the header is to be displayed. Only add them once when needed, otherwise update the existing ones.

Comment: yeah how do i do that?  I've tried removing the subviews but the app just crashes..any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: i try to remove the subviews of the header view with this:      view.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() }) and it throws this error:UITableViewHeaderFooterView's superview is not of class UITableViewHeaderFooterView

Comment: why are you using `willDisplayHeaderView` i think you should implement `viewForHeaderInSection` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Header views, like cells, are **reused**. So, when the table view sends you `tableView(_:willDisplayHeaderView:)`, it might not be the first time you've received that message for that header view. Yet every time you receive the message, you add four subviews to it.

Don't implement `tableView(_:willDisplayHeaderView:forSection:)` at all.

Instead, make a subclass of `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` with properties for the different subviews. This is just like how you created a subclass of `UITableViewCell` named `StreamTableViewCell`. Maybe you could call your header subview class `StreamSectionHeaderView`. Then you have two options for setting up the header view's subviews.

Option 1: In `StreamSectionHeaderView.initWithFrame(_:)`, create the subviews of the header view (and store them in the instance properties and add them as subviews). This is essentially what you're doing now in `tableView(_:willDisplayHeaderView:forSection:)`, but you would move most of the code into the `StreamSectionHeaderView` class. Register the `StreamSectionHeaderView` class with the table view using `UITableView.registerClass(_:forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:)`.

Option 2: Design the header view and its subviews in a XIB (you can't do it in a storyboard), connect the subviews to the `StreamSectionHeaderView` properties (which must be `IBOutlet`s in this case), and register the XIB in the table view with `UITableView.registerNib(_:forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:)`.

To produce section, implement `tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)` by calling `tableView.
dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier(_:)` and then configuring the header view's subviews, which already exist by the time `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier(_:)` returns.

#### UPDATE

Here's your `StreamSectionHeaderView`, assuming you want to set up its subviews in code:

```
class StreamSectionHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

    // Make these IBOutlets if you design StreamSectionHeaderView in a XIB.
    var beatAuthorLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(55, 5, 200, 40))
    var profilePictureImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(5, 5, 40, 40))
    var dateLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(225, 5, 200, 40))

    init(frame: CGRect) {
        profilePictureImageView.layer.borderWidth = 0
        profilePictureImageView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        profilePictureImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        profilePictureImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profilePictureImageView.frame.height/2
        profilePictureImageView.clipsToBounds = true
        profilePictureImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        profilePictureImageView.image = UIImage(named: "imgres")

        beatAuthorLabel.font = UIFont(name: beatAuthorLabel.font.fontName, size: 14)
        dateLabel.font = UIFont(name: dateLabel.font.fontName, size: 8)

        contentView.addSubview(beatAuthorLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(dateLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(profilePictureImageView)
        contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 179/255, green: 194/255, blue: 191/255, alpha:1)
        textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        alpha = 1
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

}
```

Then, in your table view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // blah blah blah other stuff

        tableView.registerClass(StreamSectionHeaderView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "Header")
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier("Header") as! StreamSectionHeaderView

        if let userPicSection = list[section] as? NSDictionary {
            if let artist = userPicSection["artist"] as? NSDictionary {
                if let profilePic = artist["profile_pic"] as? String {
                    header.profilePictureImageView.downloadImageFrom(link: profilePic, contentMode: UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit)
                }
            }
        }

        if let nameSection = list[section] as? NSDictionary {
            if let name = nameSection["artist"] as? NSDictionary {
                if let adminName = name["admin_name"] as? NSString {
                    print(adminName)
                    header.beatAuthorLabel.text = adminName as String
                }
            }
        }

        if let created = list[section] as? NSDictionary {
            if let date = created["created_at"] as? String {
                header.dateLabel.text = date as String
            }
        }

        return header
    }

}
```

Comment: I understand everything except i cant find anything on the initWithFrame...could you write a really simple example? or post a link to one?